# How to compress java app to have a minify jar as a result

Tags: java, maven, jar

Is there any possibility to have a minify JAR after the maven's project assembly?
I'm working at big java server project with Spring Framework, the final Jar archive is about 120 Mb. 
Our frontend developers added some plug-in, which compresses their part of the web application. And now i'm trying to find some way for backend.

*Maven default compress is not enough*

Comment: Frontend is compressed because it makes it faster to be download by users when they access your web page, and obfuscated because a user can read the page code. Backend is not downloaded by user, why would you compress it?

Comment: thanks, you are right, i just want to have a smaller jar for memory optimization and faster loading

Comment: Java loads classes on demand. Therefore if a class it is required you have to include it in the JAR and it will be loaded anyway. Unused classes just remain in the JAR, taking no RAM. When indexing the JAR, less classes may save some milliseconds an KBytes - but nothing that is worth the effort of minimizing the JAR (IMHO).

Comment: The big difference between JavaScript and Java is simply JavaScript is used as source code ...and minifying means removing comments/line feeds/whitespaces etc. which makes it runable by javascript but not readable anymore. Java is in contraction compiled and delivered in a JAR file format which is already compressed. The question is what you think you can reach of reduce in size? Apart from the `default compress` is the default given by Java (JAR default)..And I'm also the opinion that the effort is not worth the result...Are you running spring boot ? Or Spring in Tomcat etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise ok, i know what you mean, and only the way is to disable some unused libraries. By the way, the frontend part have some plugin to produce .gz files near the normal .js files and i need to support it on the server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome in dependency hell (I bet the majority isn't code written at your company, but coming from some "useful" libraries).

Have a look at the maven dependency tree, identify the biggest contributors, and ask your fellow developers if these libraries are really necessary (good luck!)... The fact that some `pom.xml` declares a dependency doesn't guarantee that it's really used for your application.

You'll not only get a smaller JAR, but also reduce the risk of transitive version incompatibilities in the future.

Comment: thanks, Ralf, i will try to analyze all dependencies in our pom.xml, if something can be thrown out, it will certainly help

Comment: If you use things like Spring or Spring boot where all the dependencies are already handled by appropriate Bill of Materials (BOM) you don't have version incompatibilities except you define the versions yourself which is strongly discouraged. You might safe some size...but I'm the opinion it's not worth the effort...